# nvvp in command line

Tags: java, cuda, profiler

I try to run nvvp for profiling cuda code in command line

```
nvvp ./my_app
```

But ,I get following error

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
```

I understand problem is with java not able to allocate sufficient heap to run the app. Based on what I read about this issue in SO (and else where in internet) I try following

```
java -Xmx128m nvvp ./myapp
```

It doesn't solve my problem and I get following message

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: nvvp
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: nvvp
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:319)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:264)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:332)
Could not find the main class: nvvp. Program will exit.
```

Comment: What OS do you use and what is the toolkit version? Do you see the same error when you run Visual Profiler without any arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is following that worked in my case

setenv _JAVA_OPTIONS "-Xms512m -Xmx1024m"

However, _JAVA_OPTIONS seemingly can have multiple names across the different systems, hence find the right one before using it. It shows following while it has picked up correct variable

```
nvvp ./cb_dgemm_prof
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xms512m -Xmx1024m
```

If variable is not set up properly, you might not see the line above.

Answer (score 0):

This message says that JVM was not able to allocate enough memory for the heap from OS, -Xmx/-Xms will not help in this case.

Please answer the questions I posted in a comment so we could find what is causing this problem...